# JSF 2.0 Javascript and CSS table

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2

I'm new to JSF 2.0 and I'm having troubles with js/css events.
Basically I have this html code:

```
<!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
table.hovertable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #999999;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.hovertable th {
    background-color:#c3dde0;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
table.hovertable tr {
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.hovertable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
</style>

<!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->

<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
    <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td id="here">Item 1A</td><td>Item 1B</td><td>Item 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 2A</td><td>Item 2B</td><td>Item 2C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 3A</td><td>Item 3B</td><td>Item 3C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 4A</td><td>Item 4B</td><td>Item 4C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 5A</td><td>Item 5B</td><td>Item 5C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It renders a simple table that change its color on 'mouseover'.
I want to "convert" it to JSF 2.0 code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />

    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h1>JSF 2.0 + Spring + Hibernate :)</h1>

        <h:dataTable value="#{cBean.getcBeanList()}" var="c"
                 styleClass="hovertable"
                 >
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header" id="h1">Info Header 1</f:facet>#{c.cBeanId}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Info Header 2</f:facet>#{c.name}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Info Header 3</f:facet>#{c.address}
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

but including `onmouseover` event.

In addition, `cBean.getcBeanList()` returns a `List<Object>`

Well, I think that's all, I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [don't care](http://www.ie6nomore.com/) about IE6 users, just use `:hover` pseudoselector. Add the following to your CSS.

```
table.hovertable tbody tr:hover {
    background: #ffff66;
}
```

If you do care about them for some unobvious reasons, use JavaScript.

```
var trs = document.getElementById('dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    trs[i].onmouseover = new Function("this.bgColor = '#ffff66'");
    trs[i].onmouseout = new Function("this.bgColor = '#d4e3e5'");
}
```

Call it during onload of the window or at end of the body. Note that the element ID `dataTable` in the Javascript has to be exactly the same as the generated HTML `<table>` ID of the `<h:dataTable>`.

```
<h:dataTable id="dataTable">
```

This is fancier possible with [`jQuery.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function, for the case you use jQuery.

```
$('.hovertable tbody tr').hover(
    function() { this.bgColor = '#ffff66'; },
    function() { this.bgColor = '#d4e3e5'; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to get the functionality is to use RichFaces. [The dataTable in RichFaces](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?c=dataTable) provide you with **onRowMouseOver** and other options. You can use it as:

```
<rich:dataTable onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'" onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'">
```

Otherwise you will have to cookup some javascript. Have a look at this forum thread: http://www.coderanch.com/t/212203/JSF/java/highlight-row-datatable-when-mouse (Refer to the response of Munish K Singh - 4th reply)

Comment: richfaces has problems with JSF 2.0