# jsf decorate dataTable row on mouse over/out

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

In plain html, when I want to point-out a table row, I just write:

```
<tr onmouseover="javaScript_(jQuery)_Code_To_Add_Pointed_Out_Class"
    onmouseout="javaScript_(jQuery)_Code_To_Remove_Pointed_Out_Class">
...
</tr>
```

Is there a way to do this in a `<h:dataTable>` for JSF?
Something with Primefaces or what else?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055384/jsf-2-0-javascript-and-css-table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Styling is to be done by [CSS](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/). E.g.

```html
<h:dataTable styleClass="myTableClass">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

with

```css
.myTableClass>tbody>tr { 
    background: pink;
}

.myTableClass>tbody>tr:hover { 
    background: purple; 
}
```

JavaScript hacks like in your question example are only necessary for ancient browsers which are already deprecated for long now.